# Why does Shenhua speak Japanese?

Tags: shenmue-2, shenmue

*Shenhua* (aka *Shen Hua* aka *Sha Hua* aka *Shen Fa*) "grew up in the wilderness of China, surrounded by nature" ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Shenmue_characters#Shenhua)). She "has lived in [Guilin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guilin) her whole life" ([Neoseeker](http://shenmue.neoseeker.com/wiki/Shenhua_Ling)).

In **Shenmue II**, *Ryo* meets her and she talks to him in accent-free Japanese (according to a friend of mine who speaks Japanese). In **Shenmue I** she also sings in Japanese.

Why is that?

I'm not sure, but I think her original name is Chinese. She grew up in China. She lives in China. Why does she speak perfect Japanese? Is it explained in the game? Or are there any hints?

Maybe her adoptive father taught her Japanese? Is anything known about him (yet)? Is it plausible that he knows Japanese?

Comment: [All Asians Are Alike](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AllAsiansAreAlike)

Comment: It's Japanese game. So more like http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TranslationConvention

Answer (score 3):

In yesterday’s #SaveShenmue Tweetathon, Yu Suzuki answered several questions ([#YouaskYu](https://twitter.com/hashtag/YouaskYu)).

The following question is not especially about Shenhua, but about all people in China. However, it’s probably fair to assume, for now, that it also applies to Shenhua.

Yu Suzuki [was asked](https://twitter.com/sensonishikie/status/617169080601047040) [sic]:

> I always wondered how ryo , being Japanese, could communicate so easy in China. Can ryo speak Chinese?

Yu Suzuki [answered](https://twitter.com/yu_suzuki_jp/status/617174229792894980):

> Let's not go there...

So according to Word of God, it’s (probably) not relevant to the plot that Shenhua speaks perfect Japanese.